# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'login.json' how to solve

Tags: javascript, termux

error image: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IesaI.jpg)

I tried to run the code but it resulted in an error that I could not open the json file saying that it did not exist

Comment: please do use blockquotes for errors not images

Answer (score 0):

Because it can't find the file you want. You should give the absolute path to file.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'database/registros.json'), {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function(err,data) {});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).